NamingException when attempting to add JMS Resource
I'm trying to carve out a legacy feature to put it in a standalone Spring Boot Application. I had better success adding a DataSource Resource programmatically, but currently trying to add a JMS resource in a similar fashion, but keep getting hit with
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource instance

My code:
TomcatConfig.java
[...]
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                // JMS ConnectionFactory
                ContextResource jmsConnection = new ContextResource();
                jmsConnection.setName("jms/jmsConnection");
                jmsConnection.setType("javax.jms.ConnectionFactory");
                jmsConnection.setProperty("resourceAdapter", "openejb/Resource/JmsResourceAdapter");

                context.getNamingResources().addResource(jmsConnection);
            }
        };
    }

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public ConnectionFactory jndiConnectionFactory() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jms/jmsConnection");
        bean.setProxyInterface(ConnectionFactory.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();                   // NamingException here!!
        return (ConnectionFactory) bean.getObject();
    }

Any guidance is appreciated here; I'm quite new at this modernizing topic. Is this because Tomcat does not support EJB somehow?
I tried creating a ContextResource programmatically, but having a hard time getting the lookup/binding to stick to it (somehow can't instantiate the jndiConnectionFactory bean. The stacktrace is not very helpful:
NamingException during context initialization: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource instance
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:98)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at com......CustomContextListener.contextInitialized(CustomContextListener.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:489)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:481)
    at com.............configuration.TomcatConfiguration$1.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatConfiguration.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:585)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289)


There must be more of the stack trace than that. Another 'caused by'?

I will post the full stack trace, but that is the bottomest one...

(1). Do not put EJB writing into Spring Boot (2). Spring Boot supports JMS. Please find Spring Boot docs JMS, the URL is here: "https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html" (3) Check, whether you use Spring Boot 2 or Spring Boot 3, the name of the package will be different (javax vs jakarta)

Am well aware that SB does not support EJB; not out of the box at least. From what I read, you can bring in the JavaEE libraries in as you see fit. My conundrum is that it's a legacy JavaEE monolith, and I'm only trying to carve out one feature out of it. So trying to reuse as many of the existing classes as I can. Just wondering what I'm missing from my current configuration.
